# Dúvida no setter

Tags: python, python-3.x, getters-setters

```
class Bola:

    def __init__(self, cor, circunferencia, material):
        self.__cor = cor
        self.__circunferencia = circunferencia
        self.__material = material

    @cor.setter
    def cor(self, cor):
        self.__cor = cor

    @property 
    def mostraCor(self):
        return self.__cor
```

Gente, estou fazendo esse exercício no Jupyter Notebook,  mas está dando o seguinte erro:

```
      NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-12-c66d63af7d4c> in <module>
  ----> 1 class Bola:
        2 
        3     def __init__(self, cor, circunferencia, material):
        4         self.__cor = cor
        5         self.__circunferencia = circunferencia

  <ipython-input-12-c66d63af7d4c> in Bola()
        6         self.__material = material
        7 
  ----> 8     @cor.setter
        9     def cor(self, cor):
       10         self.__cor = cor

  NameError: name 'cor' is not defined
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar? O problema está no *setter*, mas não sei como consertar.

Comment: Na verdade o problema é o *getter*, vc criou uma propriedade chamada `mostraCor`, quando deveria ser apenas `cor`: https://ideone.com/LG7cBs - na pergunta sugerida acima como duplicada, tem outras recomendações também sobre criação de getters e setters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você usa a ideia do property você pode partir de duas abordagens diferentes:

**1.** Usar a class property, na seguinte maneira:

```
algum_atributo = property(fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None)
```

Onde property retornará um objeto que irá lidar com o get, o set, e o del que foram passados como argumentos para as variadas formas de acesso do seu **"algum_atributo"**, ou seja, toda vez que você quiser, por exemplo fazer um get do atributo, o objeto irá chamar a função que você passou como o **fget** e assim em diante.

**2.** Usar o decorador @property, que funciona com a mesma função acima, a diferença é que, sob a função que ira realizar o **get** no seu atributo você irá decorá-la com o **@property**, por exemplo:

```
@property
def algum_atributo(self):
    return self._algumatributo
```

Ou seja, toda vez que você realizar o seguinte comando:

```
SeuObjeto.algum_atributo
```

Você irá chamar o método decorado pelo **@property**.
**O ponto importante que precisa ser lembrado é que**, para definir o **setter** é preciso que seja feita da seguinte forma:

```
@nome_funcao_decorada.setter
def nome_funcao_decorada(self,value):
    self._algumatributo = value
```

Onde nesse caso, pelo que fizemos, seria traduzido assim:

```
@algum_atributo.setter
def algum_atributo(self,value):
    self._algumatributo = value
```

Resumindo, você precisa utilizar o mesmo nome da função decorada pelo **@property** no decorador do setter, e ainda mais, para facilitar o uso e o entendimento, é recomendado que seja utilizado os mesmos nomes para as funções decorada.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Entendi, mas porque é necessário usar o mesmo nome da função decorada pelo @property? Eu fiz utilizando a sua primeira dica também, nela pode colocar nomes de funções diferentes.  Desses dois modos qual é o melhor de utilizar?

Comment: porque perceba,  quando você decora uma função com o "@property"  você está está de certa forma criando um objeto property com essa função, como você pode ter outras funções decoradas com o "@property" elas utilizam da sua função decorada como referencia principal, ou seja, quando vc decora uma função para o "set" com o "@cor.setter" o decorador ta chamando a função cor que ta decorador por um determinado "@property" e a partir dela utilizando o setter que agora já recebe a função que ele acabou de decorar, que nesse caso, por conveniência,também utilizamos o mesmo nome.

Comment: Sobre os modos, se vc tiver se referindo ao nome da funcao em si, é melhor sempre utilizar o mesmo nome, como se fosse um atributo que vc quer acessar. Da uma olhada aqui o objetivo do uso do property: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property